# R misreading csv files after modifications on Excel

Tags: r, excel, csv, import

This is more of a curiosity. 
Sometimes I modify csv files from Excel rather than R (suppose I manage to find a missing piece of info and I type it in the csv file), of course maintaining commas and quotes as they were. 
Every time I do this, R becomes unable to read the csv file, i.e. *it imports a single column as it appears on Excel*, rather than separating the values (no options like sep= or quote= change this). 
Does anyone know why this happens?
Thanks a lot

An example

This was readable:

```
 state,"city","county"
 AK,"Anchorage",""
 AK,"Haines",""
 AK,"Juneau","Juneau"
```

After adding the missing info under "county", R fails to import it as a data frame, reading it instead as a single vector.

```
state,"city","county"
AK,"Anchorage","Anchorage"
AK,"Haines","Haines"
AK,"Juneau","Juneau"
```

Edit:
I'm just running the basic read.csv

```
 df <- read.csv("C:/directory/df.csv")
```

Comment: It'd be easier to know if you happened to have a sample `.csv` file. Every time I face such issues the problem seems to be Excel changing something on your `.csv` file which isn't always obvious and depends on your regional settings. Setting Window's [format](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-windows-regional-settings-to-modify-the-appearance-of-some-data-types-edf41006-f6e2-4360-bc1b-30e9e8a54989#:~:text=In%20Windows%207,format%2C%20click%20Customize%20this%20format.) through the Control Panel to `english` solves most issues caused by just "opening the file on Excel".

Comment: Can you please post the first two lines of the CSV file before and after the modification through Excel? Have you tried a *diff* on both CSV files? *diff* is a Unix command line utility listing differences; OSX has a buitl in graphical utility *opendiff* and Linux comes with *diffuse*, but a mere "diff file1.csv file2.csv" should already show the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try both solutions. I added an example from the last time that happened, but this happens with many different files.

Comment: The example is a PNG image, so it is not possible to try out loading the data. Can you please post the first four lines in ASCII format?

Comment: Let me know if this is ok now. I would like to underline again though that my question was not specific to this example

Comment: Please include your `read.csv` or `read.table` lines. And show (in text) the R error or undesired result since you indicate *R fails to read it.*. I cannot reproduce with posted CSV.

Comment: I added the read.csv line. Regarding the error, I did indicate it imports a single column. It does not produce an error. That's the only issue and the only thing that changes after opening the file in Excel

Comment: The only difference that I see is that there is a white space character after the line break in the first version, that seems to have been removed by Excel. Maybe a carriage return? Can you open both files with a hex editor to check this?